# How to fix cannot read property error in foreach loop

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a foreach loop where i fetch data from firebase. 
i want to set a global variable to hold the "spotrating" (a property of each object).
But when i call the global variable inside the forEach loop i get an error "cannot set property spotrating of undefined "

when i try to log the global variable in every other part of the code it works but when i do it in the forEach loop it doesnt work

```
spotrating: any;
```

**Later in my code**

```
temparr.forEach(function(firebaseSpot) {
        console.log(this.spotrating);
 });
```

I expect to get the value of the spotrating printed out to the console but i keep getting the error. "cannot read property spot rating of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of `this` refers to your function because you did not use fat arrow notation. `spotrating` is not defined in your function. If you want `this` to refer to the outside function (the one calling it), use fat arrow notation as below. Scoping will bite you. I use fat arrow by default unless I want the scope of a callback or function to be that callback or function. Normally I don't.

```
temparr.forEach(firebaseSpot => {
        console.log(this.spotrating);
 });
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Edit: Using an arrow function is not actually changing the scope of the function as I used to think, my usage of the word scope above is not completely correct. An arrow function has its own scope.

So while scope isn't changing, the value of `this` is changing. A normal function creates its own `this` while an arrow function does not as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

> In arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical
> context's this. In global code, it will be set to the global object

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me

Comment: I'm glad I could help... as a frequent question asker. If you are using VSCode (or any decent IDE) it will show you what variables are in your scope. Learning to use the debugging in an IDE is worth a few hours of study, it'll save you a lot of time later.